# SilverStripe save and publish is taking over 60 seconds on Plesk

Tags: php, silverstripe, plesk

I have a Plesk reseller VPS and have set it up for running SilverStripe sites. For the most part the sites load well (under a second on average) and works as expected.

The admin also performs as expected, with the exception of Save and Publish. Doing a save and publish (even with one small change) takes over 60 seconds (where as a standard write action takes maybe a few seconds). This is happening for all page types. We are not using any custom `onBeforeWrite` or `onAfterWrite` calls and are not using static publisher.

On our development server (also Apache based), save and publish time is less than 10 seconds. Switching to Dev mode on live seems to make no difference.

I am kind of at a loss as to why this is happening or how to diagnose the issue. Has anyone else had this issue?

I am running SilverStripe 3.5, PHP 5.6.3 and Mysql 5.5.

**EDIT:** I have checked all the logs, the only thing being logged that I can see was the timeout error (which goes away when I increase script execution time).

**UPDATE - 13/06/17:** I have now installed a smaller (largely vanilla) SilverStripe site on the same server, Save and Publish for this site works as expected (and is very snappy).

I am assuming that this is a module causing the error. I have also contacted support, the on only thing they can think could cause this would be a script is accessing a third party server (which is being stopped by a network firewall). The only module that springs to mind would be the Live SEO module (as this talks to google for it's scoring system).

Comment: Either the Plesk server is too slow or you have some weird DataObject model and onBefore/onAfterWrite magic running. Does this happen for every page type or just some page types? Do you re-render the whole page with Static Publisher? Just some educated guesses...

Comment: The plesk server is a dedicated VPS with dedicated RAM, HDD, ETC. The server itself has way better specs than our dev server (which is now pretty elderly). The only really difference is that Apache is running using FastCGI (rather then Mod_PHP).

The site in question has about 4 page types, none make use of onBeforeWrite, onAfterWrite, etc and only have a handful of has_one associations (nothing more complex) and we are not using static publisher.

I am guessing it is configuration that is causing this? Standard save actions are completed within a second.

Comment: check your php error logs. also check if Plesk firewall is not causing problems

Comment: @PsychoMo very hard to tell from outside. Check all logs (and be sure everything is logging): silverstripe (error) log, php error log, syslog. Might be a bad php configuration causing this. RAM in machine is useless if php isn't allowed to use it. Is the cache dir writeable? Also the dir for combining javascript or css (if you use that).

Comment: @wmk Already checked logging, nothing is being reported (other than the script timeout errors, which have gone once I increased the timeout limit). PHP has 256M available, PHP config is pretty much vanilla (appears pretty much the same as our dev server). Admin JS and CSS is compiling to default dir (assets/_combinedfiles) without issue.

Comment: @NadirLatif By Plesk firewall, are you referring to mod_security? Or is there additional firewall software running (such as IP tables)?

Comment: Well the Plesk firewall is for network connections. I meant a server firewall such as SELinux or Apparmor

Comment: Are you running Xdebug on that server by any chance?

Comment: @bummzack Not to my knowedge. I will get hold of my hosting support and raise the question you guys have.

Comment: I have just added an update to this question with more details, I suspect it may be the Live SEO module, I am wondering if anyone has had similar issues?

Comment: Profiling will probably help, save and publish of a page can trigger many things.  https://github.com/amoebas/silverstripe-profiler or https://github.com/amoebas/silverstripe-dbprofiler or its a manual effort to divide and conquer to find it.  Good Luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, finally managed to get this sorted. The hosting provider were quite helpful (they usually are), it turned out to be an routing issue in their data centre.

The hosting provider told me that they had identified an issue with IP6 routing that was causing a timeout in some instances. They have resolved this and "Save and Publish" is now working as expected.

If anyone else gets this issue and has ruled out the items mentioned above, I would advise contacting their hosting provider, it may be an external issue.